# updating windows 8 to 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, .net-framework

I would like to update my PC from Windows 8 to 8.1 and right now am having the .net framework 3.5 in windows8 for SQL server running, my question is if I install the update available at windows store does windows keep enabled .net framework 3.5 after update?

Any help would be much appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The installation of 8.1 will not affect your .NET installations.